# Discord.js pat command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to make and pat command for my Discord bot but it doesn't work.

I receive the following error:

```
(node:14648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\nbabu\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Raphtalia bot\Raphtalia bot\commands\pat.js:13:26)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nbabu\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Raphtalia bot\Raphtalia bot\index.js:90:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\nbabu\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Raphtalia bot\Raphtalia bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\nbabu\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Raphtalia bot\Raphtalia bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\nbabu\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Raphtalia bot\Raphtalia bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\nbabu\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Raphtalia bot\Raphtalia bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\nbabu\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Raphtalia bot\Raphtalia bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\nbabu\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord bots\Raphtalia bot\Raphtalia bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Code**:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { patch } = require('node-superfetch');
const superagent = require('superagent');
const customisation = require('../customisation.json');

module.exports = {
  name: "pat",
  description: "Pat someone UwU",
  aliases:["pat"],
  category: "fun",

  execute: async (client, message, args, tools) => {
    if (message.mentions.users.first().id)
    return message.reply("you almost mention someone to pat them");
    
    if (message.mentions.users.first().id) 
    return message.channel.send('UwU');

    const { body } = await superagent
    .get("https://nekos.life/api/pat");
    
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .catch(body)
    .setColor("#3bb9ff")
    .setTitle(`i see that is, ${message.author.username} patted ${message.mentions.users.first().username}`) 
    .setImage(body.url)
    .setFooter(`© ${customisation.ownername}`);
    message.channel.send({embed})
}}
```

**Index.js responsabile for commands**

```js
const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.guild) return;

  const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(PREFIX)})\\s*`);
  if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return;

  const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);

  const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command =
    client.commands.get(commandName) ||
    client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

  if (!command) return;

  if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new Collection());
  }

  const now = Date.now();
  const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
  const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 1) * 1000;

  if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

    if (now < expirationTime) {
      const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
      return message.reply(
        `please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`
      );
    }
  }

  timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
  setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

  try {
    command.execute(message, args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply("There was an error executing that command.").catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

**I you see the mistake/ When i can upgrade the code please tell me.**
**My discord is IncarnateWill#6969.**
**If you need to see something else add me and i will Screen share the code of the bot.**

Comment: Can you show us how you called the `execute()` method?

Comment: it worked i neded to remove .catch(body) from pat.js

Comment: I just rolled back to a previous edit. You should only improve your post by editing, not changing the question by removing parts that have been resolved with user's help and add more errors unrelated to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `message` always has a `mentions` property even if there are no mentions (and `message.mentions.users.first()` returns `undefined` when there is no one mentioned in the message). As your code above looks correct, the only possible way `message.mentions` is `undefined` if you didn't pass the `message` object down to your `execute` method or you passed the arguments in the wrong order.

*Update:*

In your `index.js` you're calling execute like this: `command.execute(message, args)`. You need to update it with the correct arguments:

```js
// ...
try {
  command.execute(client, message, args)
} catch (error) {

// ...
```

In `pat.js`:

```js
// ...
execute: async (client, message, args) => {
  // ...
}}
```

If you've got other commands that currently work with that order, you can add `client` as the third argument, so you don't need to update them, only these two:

```
// in index.js

try {
  command.execute(message, args, client)
} catch (error) {

// in pat.js

execute: async (message, args, client) => {
  // ...
}}
```

Comment: From index.js
I don t quite understand
I am new to code.
That s all i put in Pat.js

Comment: Well, you should show us your `index.js` file then, so we can check if that's correct.

Comment: If u have Discord add me on IncarnateWill#6969
I will add the index.js part responsabile for commands in 1 min

Comment: And it does the oposite thing.
Like when i do /pat it should respond "you almost mention someone to pat them".
And when i do /pat @user it should send UwU and the embed

Comment: You're checking `if (message.mentions.users.first())` twice, the first one should check `if (!message.mentions.users.first())` probably :)